# Beamer tcolorbox boxes rendered top-bottom instead of side-side

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I am trying to get two `tcolorbox` elements to show up side by side, in equal height boxes. This was working yesterday but for some reason isn't working anymore after I presumably made changes in other parts of the presentation. What's happening instead is that the boxes show up one on top of the other, regardless of how little text I put in them. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
%\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}

\begin{frame}[t]{Applications: A Partial List} 

\tcbset{width=(\linewidth-1mm)/2,before=,after=\hfill,arc=0mm,
colframe=blue!30,colback=yellow!25,fonttitle=\bfseries}
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=A, adjusted title = {title 1}]
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item first
                    \item second
                \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox} \begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=A, rounded corners, adjusted title = {Title}]
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item first
                    \item second
                \end{itemize}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}` without a space between the two environments instead of `\end{tcolorbox} \begin{tcolorbox}`  could help.

Comment: This ^ actually worked! Thank you!!

Comment: As an alternative, you could use a `tcbraster` or a `tcbitemize`. With the last one, you can avoid some typing and be sure that both boxes go one beside the other.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you! Would you be able to demonstrate how to use those commands in my example? Thank you for the pointer, I'll also try to find this answer on my own and update my answer below if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it, with help from leandriis' comment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
%\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}


\begin{frame}[t]{Applications: A Partial List}
\tcbset{width=(\linewidth-1mm)/2,before=,after=\hfill,arc=0mm,
colframe=blue!30,colback=yellow!25,fonttitle=\bfseries}
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=A, adjusted title = {title}]
                    \begin{itemize}
                    \item first
                    \item second
                \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}%
%\end{column}
%\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=A, adjusted title = {title}]
                    \begin{itemize}
                    \item first
                    \item second
                \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```